# Opening freegisdata.org WMS in QGIS

Tags: qgis, wms, mapserver, cyprus

I'm not very familiar working with WMS/WFS. I found this list of datasets from Cyprus but I'm not able to open them in any software. Here is a link to the list of datasets:

http://freegisdata.org/place/50821/

For example I want to open Soil Threats;

http://freegisdata.org/record/urn:uuid:eccbd308-1580-45f4-ad18-87bf3cb1e44c-MS/

I tried to add WMS layer to QGIS but I'm not sure if I'm entering the right url, It doesn't work.

Comment: Please include a screenshot of the settings you are trying to use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the 'source URL', so the one on the main page you have provided or under `source URL` in the detailed page.

Taking the 1st record, the URL would be `http://www.fao.org/figis/geoserver/wms/`
Note that for the specific example you have provided, the service at [eusoils.jrc.ec.europa.eu/wrb/wms_Threats.asp?_=](http://eusoils.jrc.ec.europa.eu/wrb/wms_Threats.asp?_=) is not working. You can try by using the given URL in a web browser.

Once you have the proper URL, you can follow this [tutorial](http://www.qgistutorials.com/fr/docs/working_with_wms.html) to load the data in QGIS.

Comment: http://eusoils.jrc.ec.europa.eu/wrb/wms_Threats.asp?_=
i used this url for the soil threats, it doesn't work. Is it wrong or the service is not working?

Comment: @fatmasen it is not working